# What's the sudo apt-get install command for installing flask-cache?

Tags: python, bash, flask, pip

I can't find it anywhere and pip install is not working for me on Windows bash.

I am using a virtualenv in Windows bash. When I run a python file that has a flask cache import, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run.py", line 3, in <module>
    from app import app
  File "/mnt/c/Users/.../app/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from main import *
  File "/mnt/c/Users/.../app/main.py", line 2, in <module>
    from flask_cache import Cache
ImportError: No module named flask_cache
```

Comment: `sudo`, `apt-get`? is this Windows or Debian-based?

Comment: Using Windows Bash

Comment: I did that. I am using a virtualenv to install the package but it is still not finding it.

Comment: This is an off-site resource request -- you're asking folks to find a software package for you (literally, a package containing a software library). See #4 in "some questions are still off-topic" in https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thank you but I'm not sure what that means. I know SO isn't fond of newbie developers but I am not sure what is going on here and could really use an explanation and some help with this. I tried setting up this app on my mac and this part works fine but not on my Windows computer. I'm at a loss here.

Comment: When I do pip install Flask-Cache , it says it is already installed in my virtual env.

Comment: @srocode, it's not that we don't like newbies, it's that we don't like questions that don't isolate a specific issue and describe how to reproduce it *in detail*. Being able to write good problem reports (and figure out reproduction steps) does come with experience, admittedly, so it's something newbies are particularly bad at -- but it's a skillset worth working on; it'll not just help you here, but in "real world" environments too.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I understand but it's sort of difficult in this situation. It's private corporate code so I can't put the code or my setup in here. I'm working almost as blind as anyone else here. :/ I guess I was hoping for someone who had a similar error and can tell me how they went about fixing so I can adapt it to my issue. I make sure to document my own work clearly and properly so people don't have to guess and hopefully I can containerize this setup to save the next poor fellow some work.

Comment: so, showing how to do it here might consist of showing: (1) how you create a virtualenv; (2) how you activate that virtualenv; (3) how you install software into that virtualenv (with any logs necessary to show that pip claims that installation succeeded); (4) the *shortest possible code* that demonstrates that you can't then import a library you installed. Excluding the output, each of these steps can just be one line -- ie. (4) can be `python -c 'import mylib'`, after (3) was `pip install mylib`; if those steps 1-4 can be tested to reproduce the issue in isolation.

Comment: ...but the details matter -- if there aren't details, there's nothing for someone trying to build or test an answer to go off of.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I got you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, some of the packages were missing from the requirements file I was given. After several searches, I was able to resolve this by installing flask cache for both python 2.7 and 3 distribution.

I used `pip2.7 install PACKAGE_NAME` and check the same for `pip3 install PACKAGE_NAME` in my virtual environment.

For any newbie coders out there, it may be really difficult to get through a problem but you can do it! If you need to seek someone out to help you please reach out to me and we can pair program together and help each other out.

I will NEVER turn you away or think your question is dumb. I know how frustrating dealing with a programming problem on your own is with little to no documentation on an application you're supposed to be supporting.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use pip to install it.

pip install Flask-Cache

Comment: I did that and it's there but python file still won't run. Same thing happened with flask module and I had to use apt-get to install it.

Comment: @seerocode do you know if it installed to the correct environment? Look in your Lib/site-packages folder and see if it is in there.

Comment: Using Windows bash

Comment: Thanks Philip for trying to help me. Your solution was halfway to what eventually solved my problem.